# Is "in assistance with" correct?

Tags: word-choice

I have drafted a letter containing the statement:

> In assistance with the team, the company registered sales amounting to
>   $x in 2014-15

Is "In assistance with the team" a correct use of English?

Comment: With the team's assistance, the company ...

Comment: No. *With the assistance of*

Comment: @LittleEva That may not work due to ambiguity. Even otherwise, the apostrophe form is awkward, prefer the *of* form instead.

Comment: ***With assistance from the team**, the company registered sales amounting to $x in 2014-15*

Comment: @Kris: is there a reason why you prefer 'of' form rather than 'from'

Comment: I did not consider *from* as an option, it is not useful in this context because the assistance givers are not outsiders.

Answer (score 1):

You could use
"With the team's assistance ....."

Or for a different approach:

"Working in-tandem / alongside the team ...."

However no, in assistance with is not a good use of English. However by substituting assistance, we can construct a better application:

"In co-operation with the team ...."

Comment: Please see my comment at OP/ LittleEva above.